Can I read HTTP response with Transfer-Encoding=identity header in Golang?
Can I read HTTP response with Transfer-Encoding=identity header in Golang? Since at here shows that the official http library, net/http only support "chunked" in inbound Transfer-Encoding headers.
I'm making an HTTP POST request in golang to a http server (let's name it as AG). AG will give a response with Transfer-Encoding=identity header, like the screenshot of Postman below.

My code to send POST request to AG in golang is like the following:
ip := ag.IP
port := ag.Port
url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%s/v1.0.0/profile/disp_profile", ip, port)

jsonData, err := json.Marshal(dto)
if err != nil {
    results <- err
    return
}

resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
if err != nil {
    results <- err
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if resp.StatusCode >= 200 && resp.StatusCode < 300 {
    results <- nil
} else {
    errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Push profile to agent %s:%s failed, appname=%s, uuid=%s", ip, port, dto.AppName, dto.UUID)
    results <- fmt.Errorf(errMsg)
}

Unfortunately, I got the following error:
net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: unsupported transfer encoding: "identity"; Post "http://192.168.87.95:8079/v1.0.0/profile/disp_profile"

I searched on the web, and found at here that the net/http only support "chunked" in inbound Transfer-Encoding headers.
The server AG was writtened by my lab predecessors a lot of years ago, and its source code is very difficult to compile due to dynamic link issues. So, it is very difficult for me to change AG code and recompile it.
I have also tried some third-party golang http client libraries like gorequest, but they are also implemented on net/http, so they report the same error above.
Setting a reverse proxy PX in front of AG to do proper handling of Transfer-Encoding header may be a reasonable workaround for this issue. But before doing that, I want to make sure is there anyway to support reading http response with Transfer-Encoding=identity header directly in golang, so I can avoid the trouble of building and running the proxy PX?
Thanks a lot!

Dumb idea: if AG is hard to compile, what about binary patching it? You can probably do a straight find-and-replace to change “Transfer-Encoding” into e.g. “X-xxxxxx-Encoding” which will disable that header.

[1/2] Go is a F/OSS project, so you can easily see where in its source code the error you're seeing is produced (just git grep for "transport connection broken" and "unsupported transfer encoding"). As to the essense of the question: 1) In theory, yes, you can dodge the error by performing your request by a custom instance of http.Client which uses your own implementation of http.RoundTripper as its Transport. The problem with this approach is that you'll basically need to reimplement the default net/http transport which is very hard and error-prone.

[2/2]  2) Since Go is F/OSS, you can trivially patch its net/http and rebuild it—producing a custom build which makes binaries not exposing the error you're seeing. This is much easier than #1 but you'll need to keep track of security updates and also carry over your patch to forthcoming major releases. IOW, it's a pain in the neck. (While we're at it, note that bulding Go from sources only requires working Go installation and bash; it's a no-brainer.) Hence I'd say What @nneonneo proposed is actually the most elegant solution I can think of.

While we're at it, you might also try to look at http/httputil/reverseproxy.ReverseProxy which has ModifyResponse: if this method would be called before failing on the Transfer-Encoding header field, you could pass your requests via an in-process reverse proxy which would merely remove Transfer-Encoding: identity fields form the incoming responses.

One more option to try is to make your client send something like Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1,identity;q=0 — that is, to explicitly tell the server you do not want identity. In theory, this pledge should apply to Content-Encoding (and the server is free to "deliver" the payload encoded using Content-Encoding using another one — which it specifies in Transfer-Encoding) but who knows how the folks wrote that thing anyway; may be worth trying.

Thank for all ideas so much. I finally decide to use nginx 1.17 as a reverse proxy PX for AG, that can remove transfer-encoding: identity header. Thanks again for your help
